# Windows Phone Emulator not listed as testing device 

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, emulator, windows-phone

I have just installed Windows Phone Developer Tools on this machine which had Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate already installed. As soon as the installation completed and I created a new project, I noticed that the option to run the app on the emulator is not present.
 [image: No Emulator]

How to solve the Problem?

Comment: Just opening debug will automatically load in the emulator as you've created a WP7 app. Or is it not doing this either?

Comment: It shows "There were Deployment errors. Continue?" when I click no, nothing happens, and when I click yes it shows this error "`HRESULT: 0x89721200`"

Comment: Yes it is, and does that even matter?

Comment: I have Genuine Windows 7 Ultimate (OEM) and original copy of VS ultimate.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can run the program as dave rook mentioned,

According to your error `HRESULT: 0x89721200` it was occurred due to the following

**About hresult** HRESULT is a 32-bit value, divided into three different fields: a severity code, a facility code, and an error code. The severity code indicates whether the return value represents information, warning, or error. The facility code identifies the area of the system responsible for the error. The error code is a unique number that is assigned to represent the exception. Each exception is mapped to a distinct HRESULT. When managed code throws an exception, the runtime passes the HRESULT to the COM client. When unmanaged code returns an error, the HRESULT is converted to an exception, which is then thrown by the runtime.

To solve your problem try to find and reinstall mscorlib.dll file in your VS2010 and for more reference about your error code:

[About your hresult error code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.hresult.aspx)

At last I like to clarify that the program written by you caused the error and the software is working fine.

Comment: @Dave Rook thanks for the edit,i try to correct myself from next post

Comment: I just created a new BLANK project "Windows Phone Application" so, how can there be a Code related problem?

Comment: I will try to repair the Whole Visual Studio

Comment: @AkshatMittal as you mentioned that t shows "There were Deployment errors. Continue?" when I click no, nothing happens, and when I click yes it shows this error "HRESULT: 0x89721200"  so according to your comment the project gets deployed and it has the error,so i clarified the error code 0x89721200

Comment: But how can there be a code problem in NEW project?

Comment: for `mscorlib.dll` I am Repairing VS 2010

Comment: @AkshatMittal can you able to deploy the project now?or getting same error code?there is no need of repair please review the link about your hresult code

Comment: Please wait while VS 2010 repairs...

Comment: come to chat i try at my best to correct your problem

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4492/discussion-between-vikki-and-akshat-mittal)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Solution you are working with > Configuration Manager > Un-check all the Deploy checks.

Or either repair or re-download .net 4.0 (even re-install it).

Comment: Shows `HRESULT: 0x89721200` error.

Comment: I assume VS worked as expected previously - therefore I would re-install the W7 SDK

Comment: I just saw on the internet that there is update available for the SDK, First I will try to install that, if it fails I will reinstall and post updates as soon as possible

Comment: Anyhow Update installation did not succeed, here is the log file http://jsfiddle.net/MuD8B/show/

Comment: What anti-malware are you running? Also, try again with Windows Defender off! Are you using Microsoft Security Essentials?

Comment: Windows Defender is turned off from the time I purchased this Laptop, and I use Bitdefender 2013 Internet Security (origional).

Comment: Try disabling it and having another go (if you're happy to do so)

Comment: I am currently re-installing it without turning antivirus off, but Will try turning it off if it fails.

Comment: Nothing just worked!! Please help me.

Comment: I have been researching this - people suggest removing all antivirus / antimalware, then running a clean up program to ensure they've uninstalled before trying to re-install the software.

Comment: Can you build a standard console app (any language) and debug or does that error as well (let's try to narrow if it's VS or the SDK)?

Comment: I develop apps on Windows and they all just works for the testing. Its SDK for sure.

Comment: Ahh - Can you either repair or re-download .net 4.0 as well - even re-install it.

Comment: Why should I, because its not a .net error.

Comment: It is if the emulator requires part of .NET 4.0 which you MAY not have installed?

Comment: ok, then let me try this also..

Comment: As soon as I launch the installer, it shows "Same or higher version of .NET Framework 4 has already been installed on this computer." So I cant install it again.

Comment: hmmm - because this has solved it for other users - can you try the repair on .net 4.5 then (Assuming you have it)

Comment: I got the same error.